# Miscrosoft Account can't remember my device as trusted device inside Webbrowser control

Tags: c#, windows, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, account

I'm browsing https://www.microsoft.com/licensing/servicecenter/Home.aspx inside a web browser control.

Strangely, the setting "I sign in frequently..."(picture below) could not be remembered.

[image]

Later when I tried to browse the same URL, it keeps asking me for security code(picture below).

This works on another machine! I also used https://www.whatismybrowser.com/ and found no major difference between the two environments!

[image]
The process is ran as administrator and I even tried to "Remove all the trusted devices associated with my account" which didn't work either.

Instead IE works properly.

Comment: I think the setting is stored as a cookie, and if you use webbrowser, the cookie either does not get set, or disappears when you change/repoen the control. I am not 100% sure though, so you might find some answers online.

Comment: With further experiment, it seems a cookie issues. What could be the reason behind a same executable both ran as admin and one of them can't read/write cookies and the other can?

Comment: Maybe the internet options --> zone security of the 2 computers are different. Assuming you ran the same executable on both computers, which have the same default browser, OS, etc.

Comment: I didn't find any noticeable different IE settings between the two machines...